# How to access cookies sent from an url in windows phone application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm calling a url in my app,and that url send me a data via cookies, how should i get that data from cookies?? Like **NSHttpCookie** and **NSHttpSharedCookie** in IOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** If you're using the Windows Phone [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) control, you can try to use the [WebBrowserExtensions.GetCookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowserextensions.getcookies%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) method :

> You could use the GetCookies method to retrieve cookies associated
>   with a website if you use the WebBrowser control in your application.
>   Once you have retrieved a CookieCollection, you could use the cookies
>   to make subsequent HTTP requests to the website.

It should return a [CookieCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.net.cookiecollection%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) which contains [Cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.net.cookie%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) instances from which you'll get all the information you need.

**2.** If you're using [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/System.Net.HttpWebRequest%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), you'll find a good tutorial from msdn in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dd920298%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Basically you have to create and to populate a [CookieContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) instance from your [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/System.Net.HttpWebRequest%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to send cookies and you just have to get received cookies from the [Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.cookies%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of [HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.httpwebresponse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the other way. (It also returns a `CookieCollection`)